# ls -a shows no folder on Desktop but in GUI, i can see three folders

Tags: kali-linux, desktop

I am on Desktop and here three folders are listed, Trash, File System and Home (in GUI .

I opened terminal and typed `ls -a` in `/home/kali/Desktop` and here it is showing nothing. Why?

Comment: It would help if you could tell us which desktop environment, or at least what distro you're using. We could present you with a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

They are virtual icons which open corresponding locations or features.

In Windows you have My Computer and Trash icons which are also not actual files or folders.